# Animations and cutscenes not showing in Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

I've been playing diablo 3 for a while now and i've noticed something:

Sometimes when i level up, it doesn't show that "Level Up" picture with which runes and abilities i've unlocked.

And when i created a new character (i've started as a demon hunter and i created a barbarian), the initial cutscene didn't show. It went straight to the game.

Is it normal?

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug with D3 scenes right now where they are not playing, blizzard is trying to fix with with the next patch. There are lots of [forum posts](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12675249217) on battle.net if you want to see.

For the level up notifications you can check your options to suppress notifications.

To do this: Options -> Interface -> uncheck "In Game Toasts"

Comment: Do you have a link to one of the forum posts? Just saying they are there isn't really helpfull.

Comment: I forgot to mention that i'm playing the ultimate evil edition on ps4. The same problems occur on this version as well??

Comment: Yes, it is across all Systems.